# Folder with 3rd party dlls doesn't show up in TFS as pending?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have a folder where I drop 3rd party dlls into that is stored in TFS.

If I replace a dll with an updated version, how come it doesn't appear in my pending updates window?

(vs.net 2012)

Answer (score 0):

This will probably be because you are using a [Server Workspace](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phkelley/archive/2013/05/29/server-workspaces-vs-local-workspaces.aspx). When using a Server Workspace you must instruct TFS that you want to Change a File by performing a "Checkout", either from VS, the `tf` command line, or the shell extension in the power toys.

This is because Server Workspaces try to save resources by having the server track all changes and not by inspecting the files on disk. If, you want TFS to pick up changes when you change files in explorer, without an explicit "checkout", swap to "Local Workspaces".